# Python: correlation between some columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe

```
atm_id  cardreader_error_by_day hours_since_last_cdm_error  avg_cdm_dispense_count_distinct_day status_count    avg_cdm_delivery_status_null    related_to_status   avg_cardreader_error    avg_reply_count_distinct_day    avg_session_error_count ... status_to_transactions_gr5  avg_bna_accept_count_gr5    avg_receipt_confirm_count_distinct_day_gr5  days_since_last_cardreader_error_gr5    avg_cdm_delivery_status_not_taken_gr5   distinct_days_gr5   last_error_bna_relative_gr5 avg_mcrw_error_gr5  target  period
4481    249 0.142857    336.000000  0.728737    20  0.271263    0.100000    0.1 1.082145    0.050185    ... 0.458297    -1.0    -0.023840   -0.142857   -1.000000   -0.238076   -1.0    -1.0    1   13
27  1   0.000000    336.000000  0.701198    15  0.298802    0.000000    0.0 1.284708    0.069767    ... 0.096547    -1.0    -0.113377   0.000000    -1.000000   -0.088046   -1.0    -1.0    1   15
3338    185 0.000000    498.138333  1.231075    36  0.385390    0.111111    0.0 1.746520    0.039507    ... 0.028924    -1.0    0.200206    0.000000    0.943524    0.029059    -1.0    -1.0    1   20
```

I need to count correlation between all combination in `df` and `df['target']`
I try to use

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(df.columns, i):
        if (df[list(subset)]).corr(df['target']) > 0.4:
            print('%s correlation: %s' % (list(subset),   df[list(subset)].corr(df['target'])))
```

But it returns an error

`TypeError: invalid type comparison`

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does `(df[list(subset)]).corr(df['target'])` always give you the dimensions you expect?

Comment: The method `corr` by definition: "Compute pairwise correlation of columns".  So you can't go beyond 1 for your i.